# How to set kendogrid control to filterable mode "row"?

Tags: kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I am trying to add filtering to kendoGrid control with mode "row".
Telerik documentation says that I should set:

```
filterable: {
    mode: "row"
}
```

But when I set this is configuration, grid is still in "menu" mode.
How can I set "row" mode?

Comment: Can you please post the full code here or in jsFiddle/jsBin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question on Telerik's support forum and this is the answer they give me:

> The filter row functionality of the Grid was added in Q2 2014. I would
>   suggest updating the current Kendo UI version to more recent one.

After I updated grid to latest version, problem was solved.